# Filter Users via REST API in Quickblox

Tags: rest, quickblox

How filter work with REST API to filter users to get only active users?

For example

GET http://api.quickblox.com/users.json?last_request_at[gt]=date+1435734384

Answer (score 4):

I have found how to do that.
GET http://api.quickblox.com/users.json?filter[]=date+last_request_at+gt+2015-07-01T08:34:47Z 
This is not useful. Quickblox should revise REST API perception.

Comment: The documentation is a bit confusing.

Comment: date_last_request field really gives the last date user logged in. Or this field name is confusing or they have a bug!